# setof/3 does not seem to be removing duplicates

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I'm attempting to find the complement of a list, given a list L1, and a universal list L2 with the following code:

```
complement(L1, L2, Res):-
    setof(X, (nth0(N, L2, X), not(member(X,L1))),Res).
```

However, my results include duplicates and are not given in list form as I'd prefer:

```
23 ?- complement([1,3], [-1,1,3,5,2,4,2,55,1,0], Res).
Res = [-1] ;
Res = [5] ;
Res = [2] ;
Res = [4] ;
Res = [2] ;
Res = [55] ;
Res = [0].
```

I figured it's probably due to Prolog's built-in backtracking but I'm not sure how to work around this to go about formatting the result correctly and getting it to remove any duplicate items in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a warning from your code, about `N` being a singleton, and setof/3 *requires* that each variable 'universally quantified' get declared.
So, you have two problems that go away together: replace nth0/3 by member/2:

```
complement(L1, L2, Res):-
    setof(X, (member(X, L2), not(member(X, L1))), Res).
```

*edit*

symmetric difference could be

```
symdiff(L1,L2,Diff) :-
    setof(X,(eldiff(L1,L2,X);eldiff(L2,L1,X)),Diff).
eldiff(L1,L2,X) :-
    member(X,L1), \+member(X,L2).
```

if L1 and L2 are ordered sets, much better to use [ord_symdiff](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ord_symdiff/3)

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this both ways, i.e. not the complement but elements from both that are not in the other, i.e. symmetric difference, also using setof/findall/bagof? I have done it the long way but the above solution could it be used to achieve this ?

Comment: @ildsarria: sorry, I'm not sure. Symmetric difference can be computed - IIRC - from library(ordsets)